# Calculus inequality (easy)

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-verification, integral-inequality

I wanna prove that 
$$\forall x>1,\quad\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt - x +1 < 0.$$
Is it true that I can rewrite the inequality as 
$$\int_{1}^{x} \left(\frac{\sin(t)}{t}-t \right)dt < 0,$$ 
and since $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}<t$ for $t>1$ (trivial), the inequality holds?

Comment: It should be -1 not -t what you pull inside the integral, as you are integrating to get $-x+1$. You're logic still holds for the second part with this answer.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. Ok thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Or let $f(x)=\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt - x +1 $. Then $f(1)=0$ and $f'(x)=\frac {\sin(x)}{x}-1$ and it's is known that $\sin(x)< x$ for $x>0$. Thus $f'(x)< 0$ and $f$ is strictly decreasing. So $f(x)<f(1)=0$ for $x> 1$.

Comment: Simple and nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin(t)\leq 1$,
$$\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt < \int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}=\log x,$$
hence you just need to prove that for any $x>1$:
$$ \log x < x-1 $$
or that for any $y>0$ we have:
$$ \log(y+1) < y $$
that is equivalent to:
$$ e^y > 1+y,$$
well-known.